# C++ Unit Test Framework with Allure Report

Tags: c++, jenkins, tap, allure, python-behave

I'm starting using Allure with Python Behave for high-level BDD testing of a medium size C++ ecosystem of services.

What I get is a web page inside Jenkins with pretty and clear reports, thanks to the Allure-Jenkins plugin.

I have also some unit tests made with TAP, shown in Jenkins with another plugin.

*What I would like to get is the integration of the unit test reports inside the same Allure page*

Unfortunately, I was not able to find a C++ Unit Testing Framework directly supporting Allure reports: *does any exist?*
*Otherwise, I could I get this integration?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no Allure integrations for C++ test frameworks exist yet. But Allure supports JUnit-style XML report format that is de facto standard format for reporting test results. So if your framework can generate results in such format you can generate Allure report for it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I'll give a try!

Comment: @Dmitry Baev Did you success? would this one help?
https://github.com/systelab/cpp-gtest-allure-utilities